# Web Scraping - What's a robust and extensible approach?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ruby, web-scraping

I have some limited experience with web scraping using tools like Beautiful Soup and Nokogiri.

[image]

My approach thus far when looking for information is to first inspect the HTML elements and CSS tags, then applying the selector.  While this works, slight differences/changes among web sites would render the code useless.  Also, there have been situations where sites simply don't add the selector tags to their HTML elements, so I once had to resort to the hacky approach of selecting the style property of the element.

How would one devise a scraper that would work across multiple sites?  I'm aware that the solution would depend on the context, but is there a general good practice in doing it?  I was actually asked in an interview before this question and I had no idea.

I have tried googling but much of what I found doesn't go past the basics, and I don't know where to look.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what content you want to scrape.

Comment: What do you mean by "sites simply don't add the selector tags to their HTML elements"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to accomplish. If you want the *content* of the page (like in an article) - you should try [goose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goose-extractor/), which should give you a leg up. You can also try searching for conventional web page approaches like [meta tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en).

Either way, you should remember that this is the *World Wild Web*, and the `HTML` is a very forgiving language, which lets people design pages which are *very* hard to read by a machine. Even big sites sometimes have their proprietary breaks from conventions, which forces exceptions in your code in order to read them. Site logic may also **conflict** with conventional logic, or other major site.

This means that your code would probably consist of a lot of use-cases and exceptions.

My suggestion to you is to keep samples of pages of sites you want to scrape, and have a unit test which iterates over them and verifies the scraping results. This way, each time you find a new quirk, you can add it to your collection, and be certain that if the change you made broke some other site's scraping, you would know about it.